# How to exclude jar in final sbt assembly plugin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependency-management, sbt-assembly

I need to exclude spark and test dependencies from my final assembly jar. I tried to use `provider` but it was not working.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1" % "provided")
```

and execute `sbt assembly`.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use exclude option of assembly plugin filtering by direct name or with contains

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
    val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
    cp filter { f =>
      f.data.getName.contains("spark-core") ||
      f.data.getName == "spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar"
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is working perfectly. I have hundreds of jar and is there any better way to avoid all related dependencies of a particular artifact/group.

Comment: Isn't the disjunction superfluous there?

Comment: amazing, thank you so much you made my day. I was struggling with that for so long.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think || works. Instead use:

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {

var cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value

cp     = cp filter { f=>f.data.getName.contains("spark-core")}

cp     = cp filter { f=>f.data.getName.contains("spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar")

 }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine with the logical OR (||). It's a Boolean expression after all.