# sbt package and assembly include jars i don't want to

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt package to generate a jar, which i will deploy after in a cluster. the issue is that the sbt package command includes dependencies that i didn't specify in the build file, and these causes so many troubles when running the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer the question, here is the code:

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
    val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
    cp filter { f =>
      f.data.getName.contains("spark-core") ||
      f.data.getName == "spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar"
    }
  }
```

src: [How to exclude jar in final sbt assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894055/how-to-exclude-jar-in-final-sbt-assembly-plugin)

my problem turns out to be with the dependency: 
Com.fasterxml.jackson.case.JsonFactory

it was solved by addiding the next dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.8.8"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.8"
libraryDependencies += "com.owlike" % "genson" % "1.4"
```